# how to check if Stream.Postion update is supported?

Tags: c#, stream

I am dealing with streams, some times I need to update the `Position` of the stream. But as you know in some cases this is not supported. For example when you get your stream from a web service as in my case :)

What I am looking for here is a proper method for chekcing if the given `Stream` object accepts the `Position` update.

There are 3 fields which looks like shall work, `CanRead`, `CanSeek`, `CanWrite`. But I couldn't decide by looking at the msdn explanations of those fields in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Please help me out here.

Comment: When in doubt, surround with `try catch`...

Comment: @AndreiV Nah, not if you can find out in advance and handle it gracefully.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, I can't say I disagree. I was just thinking of "saving" an `if` statement and also some important brain cells, which could be spent on something more important.

Comment: I'd rather save a `try catch` if I just need to write an `if` to handle the situation :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [`CanSeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). From the docs:

> If a class derived from Stream does not support seeking, calls to Length, SetLength, **Position**, and Seek throw a NotSupportedException.

Comment: I just looked at the description, that's why i didn't see it :/

Answer (score 2):

`CanSeek` is the method you're looking for. Setting the `Position` property involves Seeking.

Comment: `CanSeek` is a **property**, not a method.

Comment: Think "Method" as "the way to do it", not as in OOP terms :-) He's from Sweden, so he probably (as we do in German) uses the word "method" outside of OOP if we want to tell people to apply some ... method to achieve something.

Comment: Who is from Sweden? :) I agree both of you guys ;) thanks for being so cooperative :)

Comment: I am, and @ThorstenDittmar's analysis is correct: I should have written "the way to go about it" or similar. Happy hacking!